# In an interview that is recorded, is it OK to ask what it will be used for and how long it will be kept?

Tags: interviewing

If an interviewer asks if they can record the interview (or tells you rather than ask) are there any questions that should be asked? For example is it a good idea to ask how long they will keep the recording and if it would be used just for the purpose of filling the position? I wouldn't want the recording to end up in some interview training class, for example. What if they ask you to share your screen during a recording? I think I would be comfortable sharing one window but probably not the whole screen.

Comment: Where in the world are you? Some places have laws about this and mandatory training for employees, some are just wild west, the strongest wins.

Comment: @nvoigt I'm in Canada, the company is based in the US, and the person doing the meeting was in Africa.

Answer (score 2):

You can ask.  But the person doing the interview may not know the answers you're looking for.

The interviewer probably knows the primary purpose which is, presumably, so that they or someone that isn't able to be in the interview can review your answers later.  It's often easier on everyone if there are two or three decision makers to have an interview with just one person and let the others see a recording at a later time so that they can form an independent judgement.  Depending on the type of interview, they may also want to ask an expert if someone's answer wasn't the scripted "right" answer.  In a technical interview, for example, sometimes really good candidates will give great answers that approach a problem from a perspective that we hadn't considered when formulating the question but the interviewer might want an expert in that technology to weigh in on the answer.

Most people are going to have no idea what their organization's data retention policy is for meeting recordings is.  They aren't going to know if the legal department wants the recording in case there is a discrimination claim.  They aren't going to know if someone in HR gets a wild idea to create a training video based on actual interviews.  That seems highly unlikely to me-- usually it's going to be faster to script out the scenario you want and have current employees act it out than it would be to go through hours of interviews to find the snippet that perfectly illustrates some point.  It's more conceivable that they'd run hours of video through some sort of AI just like they run resumes through AI.  But the interviewer probably has no idea about that and probably has no way to mark a recording so that if some future HR person decides to feed a bunch of recordings to an AI they know to exclude yours.

If you live in the EU, you could potentially submit a GDPR request to see what data the company has about you, what reasons they have to retain/ process that data, and potentially to ask that the information be deleted.  That seems like a fair amount of effort but it may be worthwhile for your peace of mind.

Since it's pretty common for corporate meetings to be recorded, I would assume that there are lots of recordings of me floating around.  Most of those recordings are going to be deleted without anyone ever watching them because the only thing more boring than a live meeting is watching a recording of an old meeting.  Having one more recording floating around doesn't seem like a huge deal to me.

Comment: Maybe at certain companies it's common to record meetings but I'm not sure if I'd say it's "pretty common".

Comment: We’ve never recorded a single remote interview at our US-based company. I find it really odd. Regardless, even if the interviewer doesn’t know their company’s data retention policies or uses for the recording, they should be able to forward the questions on and get an answer. The candidate should be made aware that the interview may be recorded when scheduling the interview.

Comment: If the interviewer doesn't know the answer (and I certainly wouldn't if a candidate were to ask me), and the candidate insists on an answer before proceeding with the interview, then they should be aware that their resume may just get "filed" in the "difficult to work with" basket and never receive a follow-up.

Comment: @brhans the interviewer also should know that their company might end up in a similar drawer by candidates. it's a two way street. A good recruiter/interviewer will offer to go without recording if they cannot answer satisfactorily or make it clear that the recording is required and ideally offer to reschedule if the recording policy is paramount to an interviewee. However, the latter bit obviously depends on the supply and demand situation. But if you surprise a candidate with an unusual procedure that you cannot completely explain, you better offer to get that information before you proceed.

Comment: According to GDPR (EU laws), not only you have the rights stated in the answer, but you have to be informed beforehand about the treatment of your personal data. Video recordings fall into this category. However, if the reason of treatment is a "legitimate interest" of the company, they don't need your consensus.